# How to extract a ZIP file from a HTTP resource with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to extract a ZIP file from a HTTP resource with node.js?

I tried the the below code but got an error indicating the ZIP file may be corrupt (which it isn't):

```
require('node-zip');
var request = require('request');

request('http://data.geo.admin.ch.s3.amazonaws.com/ch.meteoschweiz.swissmetnet/data.zip', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(new JSZip(body, {base64: false, checkCRC32: true}).files);
  }
})
```

Error:

> Error: End of data reached (data length = 230973, asked index =
>   261475). Corrupted zip ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` tries to decode the content as text, corrupting your data. Try with :

```
request({
  method : "GET",
  url : "http://data.geo.admin.ch.s3.amazonaws.com/...",
  encoding: null // <- this one is important !
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(new JSZip(body).files);
    // handle error
    return;
  }
});
```

See also http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html (the `request` example at the bottom of the page).